# Cant change blender default version. All my blend files keep opening up in older version

Tags: interface, versions, conversion

So far my main version I was working with was 3.0. I got 3.5 (also tried 3.3) and when I try to make those versions default, even newer files ive saved through them open up in 3.0

Any ideas?

Comment: It might help if you said what operating system you are using.

Comment: Did you use Edit -> Preferences -> System -> Make Default?

Comment: @JohnEason Im on Win 10

Comment: @AllenSimpson yes I have tried the make default button on all 3 versions that I mentioned. Doesnt seem to work

Comment: Worked fine here under Windows 10 Professional for every version I installed.

Comment: @JohnEason I cant even try to uninstall 3.0 because thats my main version

Comment: You don't need to uninstall any version of Blender if you have enough disk space. They all run independently with their own settings. I currently have 5 versions installed here and using the setting that @AllenSimpson suggests in one of the versions means that double-clicking a Blend file opens it in that version.

Comment: Same thing here with Window 10 Home. I need to change the default app for .blend files in OS everytime. Maybe the simplest way: Windows Explorer > RMB at any .blend > Properties > Opens with: Change > More Apps > Search Other Apps (scroll down) > select BlenderVersion. Here they are linked to desktop with number else you find them in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\[BlenderVersion]\blender.exe

Comment: Got rid of blender 3.0 and got 3.2, .3, and .5 instead. It works now, but somehow I had to uninstall 3.0